# Reset user desktop to its default

Tags: unity, gnome

I've been searching and no answer seems to apply. 
I've got Ubuntu 12.04 with 2 users created. One of the users messed up her desktop (top panel stretched out, left panel disappeared, windows have close button only -no minimize, no restore-), the other user's desktop is fine as always was. I don't have a clue what the first user has done to mess it up, but I need to somehow reset that desktop configuration to its default, how can I do that?
I've tried `unity --reset` and it doesn't work (doesn't seem to finish running).
As I said: I only want to reset that particular user's desktop configuration, because I even created a new user and the configuration after creation of that new user is fine.
Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: left of top panel shows the option "Activities", which I don't see in any other installation of 12.04. In the middle of the panel is the weekday and time of the day, in the right hand side of the panel, 4 icons: universal access, volume, network and user-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said above, she's somehow installed the GNOME desktop. You should be able to go back to unity by: on the log in screen, click the little ubuntu icon by their username and choose ubuntu instead of gnome.

You can also fully remove it by:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user is using GNOME 3 with GNOME Shell! You can purge GNOME 3 and reinstall it but it's the same as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

She probably has just selected the Gnome desktop on login - click on the Ubuntu icon on the user's login prompt, and select 'Ubuntu'/'Unity':
[image]

This is also possible using Gnome's default login manager *(select 'Ubuntu'/'Unity' again)*:
[image]